# Can a country declare all its mercenaries as its soldiers?

Tags: law, rules-of-war

[Ukraine hopes to save foreign soldiers sentenced to death, says lawmaker](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/ukraine-hopes-save-foreign-soldiers-sentenced-death-says-lawmaker-2022-06-11/)

> Britain has condemned the sentencing of the fighters as an "egregious breach" of the Geneva Convention, under which prisoners of war are entitled to combatant immunity and should not be prosecuted for participation in hostilities.
>
> Ukraine, which has dismissed the Donetsk court's ruling as having no authority, says the fighters had signed contracts with the Ukrainian armed forces.

Does this mean that, by definition, it is impossible for there to be any mercenaries in the Ukrainian armed forces? Since even if they are fighting entirely for personal profit (the definition of "mercenary"), Ukraine can still sign a contract with them and call them Ukrainian soldiers.

Nothing specific to Ukraine about this question; it could equally apply to e.g. Wagner Group soldiers fighting in Syria (becoming officially Syrian soldiers).

If the answer to the title question is "yes", what is the point of having separate rules for mercenaries since if the rules are sufficiently harsh then all mercenaries will magically become soldiers?

Comment: Generally speaking however, most private military contractors don't want to enlist in 3rd world countries' armies as such... for reasons of pay and whose laws they'd be subject to etc. Recall the exceptions that western PMCs had secured in Iraq etc. Probably something less formal happened in Syria with the Russians. OTOH you couldn't expect ISIS to respect the Geneva conventions anyway, so "mercenary' status, which PMCs [technically](https://www.everycrsreport.com/reports/RL32419.html#_Toc222889752) were subject to, didn't really matter much relative to the other issues I mentioned.

Comment: @Fizz if that's how it works I imagine one could have a plausible deniability arrangement - if you are captured then you are our soldiers, otherwise (or if you do some kind of war crime) you are private military contractors.

Comment: "Since even if they are fighting entirely for personal profit..." Is this the case here? I had the impression that many foreign fighters supporting Ukraine are not in it for the profit and if they are, my estimation would be that the risk for their lives still far outweighs any potential financial profit. I mean, what exactly are they supposed to loot or do mercenary stuff on?

Comment: This is essentially what the French Foreign Legion is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While a regular soldier does receive some form of "compensation" (at least food, shelter, experience and medical treatment), this is usually far from sufficient to attract enough fighters that have no other reasons to risk they lives, apart for pure money. This is why [Geneva convention](https://www.ohchr.org/en/node/3383/international-standards) says that the payment must be **substantially** higher:

> material compensation substantially in excess of that promised or paid to combatants of similar ranks and functions in the armed forces of that Party;

This requires special, separate and different contract with these people. They would not accept just an ordinary enlistment.

Comment: "They would not accept just an ordinary enlistment": if there is an ordinary enlistment, there is no need to consider the question of how much anyone is getting paid, because any member of the armed forces is excluded from the definition of "mercenary."

Comment: Another point that excludes the people mentioned in the question from the definition of "mercenary" is that they are residents of Ukraine.  So there are at least three factors present, any one of which suffices to guarantee them the protection of the Geneva conventions.

Comment: Slight nitpick, that [def is](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/en/customary-ihl/v1/rule108) in AP I. Not all countries have signed up to that. Also "At the Diplomatic Conference leading to the adoption of the Additional Protocols, Afghanistan, Cameroon, Cuba, Mauritania, Nigeria and Zaire expressed their opposition to this formulation. Cameroon, for example, stated that “it would be very difficult to prove that a mercenary received exorbitant pay”. The Netherlands was against any reference to the motivation of a mercenary altogether. [...]"

Comment: "The OAU Convention against Mercenarism dropped the requirement of material compensation “substantially in excess of that promised or paid to combatants of similar ranks and functions”. The UN Mercenary Convention, however, does contain this requirement. [...] The legislation of 11 States of the former Soviet Union define mercenaries with respect to their desire for private gain without further qualification." That included both Ukraine and Russia when that piece was written.

Comment: Why "it would be very difficult"? Take the salary of the mercenary, take the payment for the ordinary recruit and compare them. Both are unlikely to be very secret: the payment for the mercenary soldier is likely advertised in order to recruit them, the payment for ordinary recruit is part of the official information.

Answer (score 7):

### Legionnaires are not Mercenaries

There's a couple of ways a foreigner can serve a state in a war, and they are clearly defined in this [excellent paper](https://direct.mit.edu/isec/article-abstract/46/1/147/102854/Leaning-on-Legionnaires-Why-Modern-States-Recruit?redirectedFrom=fulltext) on Legionnaires from about a year before the invasion of Ukraine.

- A Legionnaire is openly employed by a State
- A Mercenary is openly employed by a Private Military Company (PMC)
- Spies and Collaborators are covertly employed by a State

Under these definitions, none of the foreign fighters in Ukraine have ever been Mercenaries.

Similarly, the Canadians who joined the Union in the US Civil War to help end slavery, and the Soviets who were conscripted by the German army in WWII were also Legionnaires.

The French Foreign Legion, British Ghurkas, US [MAVNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Accessions_Vital_to_National_Interest) program are all more recent examples of Legionnaire programs.

You can tell fighters working for Blackwater and Wagner are Mercenaries, because you can name the PMC that they work for.

Here's a [podcast](https://www.lawfaremedia.org/article/lawfare-podcast-all-about-legionnaires) from the paper's author discussing the how the Ukrainian case fits into her theory.

Comment: Also the Americans who joined the British forces in 1940.

Comment: @DJClayworth - the author of the linked paper identified >200 examples of Legionnaire programs since 1815, including every major combatant in WWI and WWII. It's an impressive piece of research.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that, by definition, it is impossible for there to be any mercenaries in the Ukrainian armed forces?

We can sidestep the question of whether the quoted passage has this meaning.  Instead, let us consider the definition of "mercenary":

> Article 47
>
> ...
>
> a mercenary is any person who:
>
> ...
>
> (e) is not a member of the armed forces of a Party to the conflict;
>
> ...

(As quoted in [my answer to another question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/73269/6927))

Therefore, by definition, it is impossible for there to be mercenaries in any country's armed forces, as the term is defined for the purposes of the Geneva conventions.

Comment: I think this is side stepping the intent of the question as it is asking if someone can start as a mercenary and join the country's armed forces and gain the protections from being a member of it under the Geneva convention. The other answers are suggesting it is possible for a mercenary to join and it doesn't matter if they are no longer considered a mercenary or not.

Comment: @JoeW I don't see anything in the question suggesting that the people under discussion started as mercenaries and were subsequently inducted into the armed forces, but even if that's what happened, they are not classed as mercenaries if they are members of the armed forces.  Has there been any claim that they are not _bona fide_ members of the Ukrainian army?  If so, that is a factual question for a court to rule on.

Comment: If they are declaring mercenaries as soldiers how could they not start out as mercenaries?

Comment: @JoeW The soldiers in question were never mercenaries. They have lived in Ukraine for several years, have families there, and enlisted into the Ukrainian army before the current war started.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Okay, so why would they become mercenaries if the question is asking about making them soldiers?

Comment: @JoeW the question is asked from a misunderstanding of the meaning of the term "mercenary."  Furthermore, there are also cases where the common understanding of "mercenary" might apply where the person nevertheless does not satisfy the Geneva convention definition.  For example, someone who chases conflict around the globe, enlisting successively in different countries' armies in order to pursue a life of active combat, might be considered a "mercenary" by most people, but such a person is not a mercenary under the convention.

Comment: I am not sure that is accurate, someone could be a mercenary that goes to a country to help fight and later joins that county's armed forces. If that happens they would have been a mercenary that is now a member of an armed forces.

Comment: @JoeW if they start fighting before they enlist then they might be mercenaries under the convention, but there would be several other tests they would have to satisfy for that to be the case, namely to have been recruited specifically to fight in that conflict, to be paid a lot more than regular soldiers, to be a foreigner and not resident locally, and not to be a foreign soldier on official duty. But my hypothetical is to demonstrate that some people who would be called "mercenaries" in common use are not under the convention.  Therefore, I specified "enlist...in order to pursue."

Comment: @JoeW in the case you contemplate, there could be a _former_ mercenary who is a member of the armed forces, but once the mercenary takes the pay cut and enlists, the person is no longer a mercenary _under the conventions_ and is therefore entitled to be treated as a prisoner of war.  Perhaps the legal situation for acts committed before enlistment is interesting, but it doesn't change the person's entitlement to be excluded from the definition of "mercenary."  Perhaps an attempt to add a mercenary to the military rolls after capture would fail, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: And I don't see the question about them being both a mercenary and a member of the armed forces but if a mercenary can be made into a member of the armed forces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137056/discussion-between-phoog-and-joe-w).

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding the answer is Yes, a country is allowed to accept any mercenary that it wants to into their regular forces and count treat them as soldiers. There are no citizenship requirements to join an countries military and an example of that is the US military. Non-citizens are allowed to join the military and they are just not able to hold all jobs and can't get the higher security clearances.

Now to the question as why the separate rules I would assume that is because mercenaries are not always working for a country or are doing so in a way to hide the link. The issue with the rules of war is that they are dealing with conflicts between countries and mercenaries don't always fit the rules.

Also just because a country can accept a mercenary into their forces doesn't mean they want to as that country would now be responsible for all the acts of that mercenary.

Comment: I think that last line is key.  By accepting the mercenary into the army, the county is also accepting responsibility for anything they do - the same as any other soldier.  If your enlisted mercenaries go on to commit war crimes, you're now on the hook for that.  Whereas if they were just hired but not enlisted, you could just disavow their actions.  (Which may or may not help reputationally, but should get the country off the hook legally/)

Answer (score 0):

> **Question:**
>
> Can a country declare all its mercenaries as its soldiers?

**Yes**, the U.S. has declared foreign countries mercenaries it's soldiers before.

In WW2 prior to United States direct military involvement it was desperate to keep China in the war.  President Roosevelt recruited and signed secret agreements with American pilots both Army and Navy to become mercenaries and fight and fly for China.  The agreement stated that if the United States entered the war the pilots would be given their previous ranks and re-enter the U.S. Service in which they had previously served.   The American fliers became known as the Flying Tigers.   After Pearl Harbor The U.S. Army drafted the entire band of American mercenaries into it's ranks as first lieutenants.  Flying Tiger, Greg "Pappy" Boyington who was a captain in the U.S. Marine Corps prior to taking the mercenary position to pay his gambling bills, deserted the Flying Tigers just prior to the drafting of the organization and returned to the United States.  Boyington who would become the top American ace in the pacific theater for a time, medal of honor winner and Japanese POW; thus spent the first year of the war parking cars in Baltimore Md. trying to get his U.S. Marine commission back.

This is what I remember from reading Boyington's autobiography.  Which is a great read.  My take away is,  yes.  If the U.S. could draft mercenaries who were fighting with China into the U.S. army over their objections,  they could certainly draft their own mercenaries if they thought it was in their best interest.

> If the answer to the title question is "yes", what is the point of having separate rules for mercenaries since if the rules are sufficiently harsh then all mercenaries will magically become soldiers?

The definition of a Mercenary in article 47 of the Geneva convention has to do with foreign nationals not party to a war, recruited abroad, and doing the soldiering for personal gain.  So don't think a nation drafting it's mercenaries into it's military would effect how the Geneva Convention categorizes them.

> **[The Practical Guide to Humanitarian Law](https://guide-humanitarian-law.org/content/article/3/mercenaries/)**
>
> As defined by Article 47 of Additional Protocol I to the Geneva Conventions, a mercenary is any person who:
>
> 1. is specially recruited locally or abroad,
> 2. does, in fact, participate directly in the hostilities,
> 3. is motivated to take part in the hostilities essentially by the desire for private gain and, in fact,
>    is promised, by or on behalf of a party to the conflict, material
>    compensation substantially in excess of that promised or paid to
>    combatants of similar ranks and functions in the armed forces of
>    that party
> 4. is neither a national of a party to the conflict nor a
>    resident of a territory controlled by a party to the conflict;
> 5. is not a member of the armed forces of a party to the conflict; and
> 6. has not been sent by a State that is not a party to the conflict on
>    official duty as a member of its armed forces.